# Total derivative of $F(f)(s) = \int_0^s \cos(f(t)^2)\, dt$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X = C([0,1])$ be the Banach space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the supremum norm and define a map $F: X \rightarrow X$ by $$F(f)(s) = \int_0^s \cos(f(t)^2)\, dt$$ for $s \in [0,1]$. Show that $F$ is totally differentiable and find the derivative for each $f \in X$.

What I have done so far: take $h \in X$. Then 
\begin{align}
F(f+h)(s) &= \int_0^s \cos((f(t) + h(t))^2) \, dt\\
&= \int_0^s \cos(f(t)^2 + 2f(t)h(t) + h(t)^2) \, dt.
\end{align}

I am stuck here. The derivative should have something to do with $2f(t)h(t)$ I believe. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Am I missing some easy trig identity that simplifies this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Recall $\cos (x + y) = \cos x + (-\sin x)y +0(y^2)$ as $y\to 0.$ So

$$\cos (f^2 + 2fh+ h^2) = \cos (f^2) +[-\sin (f^2)](2fh +h^2) + O((2fh+ h^2)^2).$$